# How to fix y-intercept value in linear regression?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a least square line across my data using scipy's `linregress()` with something like this:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

y = [30, 60, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81]
x = np.arange(0,9)

grad, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

However, I would also like to fix the y-intercept at a particular point.

Ideally, I'm planning to fix it at the first value in `y` list. In other words, what I'm really trying to do is I want the best fit line to pass through the first value in the `y` list, which is 30 in my example.

But it seems like Scipy is deciding the y-intercept for me.

How can I fix the y-intercept to a particular value in scipy's linear regression method?

*PS*: I've also tried using statsmodels' OLS, but it only allows me to either stay at y-intercept=0 or let it decides the best intercept for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In statsmodels you can shift y so the origin is at zero and exclude the intercept:

```
res = OLS(y - 30., x).fit()
```

where x contains the regressors without intercept (column of ones). Then the interpretation is that we predict the deviation from 30.

```
y_predicted = 30 + res.predict(...)
```

Almost all statistic, like bse, tvalues, pvalues and fit statistics like rsquared, are independent of the shift in location assuming the constant is fixed at the shift value.

Answer (score 0):

In a polynomial equation such as a parabola:

Y = a + bX + cX^2

when X = 0, then Y = a and so if you are fitting a polynomial and can use a fixed value for a, you can make the Y intercept equal to any value you wish. Again using the example of a parabola, if you fit data to the equation:

Y = 7.5 + bX + cX^2

then the fitted intercept for the above equation will be 7.5.